# Power BI Join multiple Tables with Slicer on each of them into one Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

To create a Sales List I have the date of former customers and their appearance on shows with their interests at that show.

I need to see if they applied for the upcoming show and see the data from former shows in one visual.
I also need to be able to filter the shows I want to take into consideation.
[image]

1. From the first Table I only need to know if the Customer has applied for the selected show.
2. The second Tabel provides the information about the Customer on my last main show.
3. From the third Table on I would like to see if the Customer participated by showing their interests.
4. Just like on step (3.) I will have more tables with the interests of Customers to pic. This will be just copies of the MainEvent Table with less information.

For each of the table I have to be able to use a different show picked by individual slicer.
Since Slicer affect each other if the tables are in a relation to each other, I was not able to filter as wished.
Can please someone help me build the required measures an relation.
Unfortunatly I do still not have a lot of experience in DAX so please help as detailed as possible.

Here I provide example date as SQL:

```
--NewEvent
Select 'Show 2023' as Show, 'A1' as AccountNo, '' as HasApplied union all
Select 'Show 2023' as Show, 'A2' as AccountNo, '' as HasApplied union all
Select 'Show 2024' as Show, 'A2' as AccountNo, 'Yes' as HasApplied union all
Select 'Show 2024' as Show, 'A3' as AccountNo, '' as HasApplied union all
Select 'Show 2024' as Show, 'A4' as AccountNo, '' as HasApplied

--CompareMainEvent
Select 'Show 2022' as Show, 'A1' as AccountNo, 'Mig GmbH' as Name, 'Cows' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2022' as Show, 'A2' as AccountNo, 'K&S' as Name, 'Chicken' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2023' as Show, 'A1' as AccountNo, 'Mig GmbH' as Name, 'Cows' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2023' as Show, 'A2' as AccountNo, 'K&S' as Name, 'Chicken' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2023' as Show, 'A4' as AccountNo, 'LTD ltd' as Name, 'Pig' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2024' as Show, 'A2' as AccountNo, 'K&S' as Name, 'Crop' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2024' as Show, 'A3' as AccountNo, 'Infini' as Name, 'Crop' as Interests

--CompareEvent_2
Select 'Show 2022' as Show, 'A1' as AccountNo, 'Horse' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2022' as Show, 'A2' as AccountNo, 'Bunny' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2023' as Show, 'A1' as AccountNo, 'Cows' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2023' as Show, 'A2' as AccountNo, 'Chicken' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2023' as Show, 'A4' as AccountNo, 'Pig' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2024' as Show, 'A2' as AccountNo, 'Crop' as Interests union all
Select 'Show 2024' as Show, 'A3' as AccountNo, 'Crop' as Interests
```